# Clash between siunitx and AASTeX

Tags: tables, siunitx, aastex

I am encoutering an issue when trying to use the table formatting provided by siunitx in a AASTeX document.

```
\documentclass{aastex631}
\let\tablenum\relax
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document} 
    
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 1.2e2]|S[table-format = 1.2e2]}
 1.23e45 & 6.78e9 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(the `\let\tablenum\relax` is already here to solve some conflicts between the two, as described in [AASTeX Author Guide](https://journals.aas.org/aastexguide/#conflicts)

I am simply trying to define two columns with siunitx formatting and I get the following error:

```
Misplaced alignment tab character &.
You have placed an alignment tab character '&' in the wrong place. If you want to align something, you must write it inside an align environment such as \begin{align} … \end{align}, \begin{tabular} … \end{tabular}, etc. If you want to write an ampersand '&' in text, you must write \& instead.
```

If I replace `aastex631` by `article` in the first line or if I only define one S column, the issue disappears. But in my real case, I need to use `aastex631` AND to define at least three S columns.

Do you know where the issue could come from, and how I could solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It seems that `aastex631` is require that you should have installed obsolete `revtex4-1` class. I you not forced (for some reason) to use aastex632, rather use `article.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I really have to use `aastex631`. Howver, I could work with an alternative to `siunitx` to write scientific format in tables.

Comment: Try with  `dcolumn` package.

Comment: Hi. I work for the AAS Journals. The error I get with your MWE is different from the one you list. My compile specs are: siunitx 2020/02/25 v2.8b; XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021)  (or pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021)             ```! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.8  1.23e45 & 6.78e9 \\```

Comment: @Gus most people will be on siunitx v 3 by now, you are still on 2.x in texlive 2021? You must be on an early, not updated, texlive 2021, my tl2021 has siunitx v 3 2021-05-17

Comment: @Zarko an excellent package:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class makes the `&` active and disturbs the parsing of siunitx. It seems to work if you add a `\relax`

```
\documentclass{aastex631}
\let\tablenum\relax
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 1.2e2]|S[table-format = 1.2e2]}
 1.23e45 \relax & 6.78e9 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's working. To complete, it seems we need a `\relax` at the end of each siunitx cell (except the last one of course) e.g., `1.23e45 \relax & 1.23e45 \relax & 1.23e45 \\` I am wondering if there is a way to automatize the process (not having to add by hand every time), but I will work with this workaround for now.